# Keeping SwiftUI macOS App Running in the Background When Window Is Not Focused

Tags: swift, macos

I am making a macOS app that involves the user pressing a key, and a function is performed accordingly. But when the focus is moved away from the app window, the shortcuts don't work. How can I make the app continue running in the background even when its window is not focused? I want to ensure that certain processes or tasks can continue to execute even if the app's window loses focus when shortcuts are pressed.

Tried using background tasks and packages like HotKeys. It works when used with modifiers for shortcuts like command, option, and a key. I just want the task to occur even when single key is pressed.

Comment: A macOS process will continue to run whether or not its window is focused. You don't need to change anything to make this happen. Regarding shortcuts, if you want to listen to key events while your window is focused, you can add a global event listener: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535472-addglobalmonitorforevents

Comment: Is the question about running processes in the background or about shortcuts?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is something [like this](https://i.imgur.com/VexOBTu.mp4)

Comment: What i am seeing in your linked gif has nothing to do with hotkeys. Also, the first app does nothing after it goes to  background , so what’s the point?

Comment: Please edit your question, post reproducible code and focus on a single problem to be solved.